# Can't install PHP after apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: apache-2.2, apt, php5, upgrade

I had a server with perfectly running for months classical LAMP installation on Ubuntu 8.04:

```
Linux localhost 2.6.24-23-generic #1 SMP Wed Apr 1 21:47:28 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=8.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hardy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS"
```

Don't know why I've started `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` but everything ended with `apt-get dist-upgrade` :) Everything gone alright... But now I can't start nor Apache, nor PHP, because PHP was simply deleted. When I'm trying to install it:

```
> apt-get install php5
<...>

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5: Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.17) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.17) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

When I'm trying to install libapache2-mod-php5:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libapache2-mod-php5: Depends: php5-common (= 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.17) but 5.3.6-6~dotdeb.1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I don't know what 5.3.6-6~dotdeb.1 is and where is this package, because I've already removed dotdeb repository from APT sources :/

Tried to do `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get install php5 php5-common php5-cli` with no success...

Don't know what to try next :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this first:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-common
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have installed some dotdeb packages (you can find them [here](http://www.dotdeb.org/)) and after removing the repository urls from sources.list apt cannot find the right packages to satisfy your installation request.
My advice is to remove all installed packages from dotdeb and then try again with apt-get install.

To start, try doing this:

```
dpkg -r php5-common
apt-get install -f
apt-get install --reinstall php5 php5-common php5-cli
```

Repeat if needed for any other package from dotdeb that you find.